# Multiple apps in an Application Service Environment

Tags: azure

I have an Azure ASE running with one web app in there. The ASE is configured with the minimum 2 frontend and 2 backend VMs.

I now want to add a second app into the ASE. Does this mean I need to increase the number of backend VMs, or can I use the existing 2 backend VMs to host both apps? I'm assuming both apps can use the same worker pool, but is that true also? Do I need to create two application service plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource pool for your Web Apps is the App Service Plan. In the context of an ASE, the App Service Plan is a *dotted line* and enforces compute resource boundaries. The real compute resources ("hardware") reside in Worker Pools. An App Service Plan can span 1 or more instances in a Worker Pool.

Here's a bird's eye view:

```
             WORKER POOL 1
   **********************************
   *                                *
   *      App Service Plan "A"      *
   *     +--------------------+     *
   *     |      Web App 1     |     *
   *     |      Web App 2     |     *
   *     |      API App 1     |     *
   *     |      API App 2     |     *
   *     +--------------------+     *
   *                                *
   **********************************


             WORKER POOL 2
   **********************************
   *                                *
   *      App Service Plan "B"      *
   *     +--------------------+     *
   *     |      Web App 3     |     *
   *     |      API App 3     |     *
   *     +--------------------+     *
   *                                *
   **********************************
```

You can mix and match, i.e. Worker Pool 1 (3 instances) could host both App Service Plan A (let's say 2 instances) and App Service Plan B (1 instance).

[App Service Environment v2 will get rid of worker pools and make scaling out straight forward](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt797651.aspx)

Comment: That is very clear thanks. So in the diagram, in the case of Worker Pool 1 I would need 4 VM instances, and in Worker Pool 2 I would need 2 VM instances?

Comment: You can scale Worker Pools independently. You can then scale the App Service Plans to take advantage of the new instances added to the Worker Pool, which in turn means more horsepower for the apps in the App Service Plan. There is no VM-to-apps binding. It's just apps-to-pool-of-resources. You could have 1 App Service Plan with 26 Web Apps on 1 Worker Pool with 2 instances. Or 6 App Service Plans on 3 Worker Pools (each plan spanning 2 instances). All up to you.